# Remove space in between words in php

Tags: php, regex, string

How do I remove space between two words in php. For example `'Hello World'` should return `'HelloWorld'`. 
I tried using `trim()` but it did not work.

Comment: Did you used google only once? Or just tried yourself something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$str = str_replace(' ', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

`trim` used for remove spaces at begin and end of string. look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

[try it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
preg_replace("/\s+/", "", $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete code:

```
$string="Hello World";
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
function space_trim($st) {
        return @str_replace(" ","",$st);
    }
    echo space_trim("   a fff     jjj    ");
```